# UnicodeEncodeError with csvwriter

Tags: python

I have one more error to fix.

```
row = OpenThisLink + titleTag + JD
        try:
             csvwriter.writerow([row])
        except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
             pass
```

This gives the error (for this character: "ń")

```
row = OpenThisLink + str(titleTag) + JD
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to fix this by using the method [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/UnicodeDecodeError). But,

```
>>> title = "hello Giliciński"
Unsupported characters in input
u = unicode(title, "latin1")

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
     u = unicode(title, "latin1")
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
>>> title = "ń" Unsupported characters in input
```

According to documentation:

> Unlike a similar case with `UnicodeEncodeError`, such a failure cannot be always avoided.

And indeed, my exception doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Link to documentation: http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And indeed, my exception doesn't seem
>   to work. Any suggestions?

`row = OpenThisLink + titleTag + JD` is outside the try/except block and so any exceptions raised while that statement is running will not be caught. This, however, will catch the exception:

```
try:
    row = OpenThisLink + titleTag + JD
    csvwriter.writerow([row])
except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
    print "Caught unicode error"
```

But, in the code that you posted, `row = OpenThisLink + titleTag + JD` will not raise UnicodeEncodeError if `titleTag` contains a unicode string; the result of the string concatenation will be of type unicode.

Now, the csv module doesn't support unicode, so when you call `writerow()` with unicode data this will raise UnicodeEncodeError. You need to encode your unicode strings into a suitable encoding (UTF8 would be best) and then pass that to `writerow()`, for example:

```
>>> titleTag = "hello Giliciński"
>>> titleTag
'hello Gilici\xc5\x84ski'
>>> type(titleTag)
<type 'str'>
>>>
>>> titleTag = titleTag.decode('utf8')
>>> titleTag
u'hello Gilici\u0144ski'
>>> type(titleTag)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
>>> csvwriter.writerow([titleTag])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0144' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
>>> # but this will work...
>>> csvwriter.writerow([titleTag.encode('utf8')])
```

The relevant Python documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). Be sure to look at the [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples), in particular the last one.

BTW, `pyshell` doesn't seem to accept non-ascii characters as input so use the normal Python interpretter.

Answer (score 1):

For IDLE, according to the solution here([link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/543035-typing-utf-8-characters-idle)), open file $python/Lib/idellib/IOBinding.py, forcefully put

> encoding = "utf-8"

after the try-except-pass module for setting locale. Close IDLE and save the file(perhaps requires administrative priority) and open IDLE again. At least it works for me. My IDLE version is 1.2, python: 2.5.