# Python STILL won't allow Japanese Characters despite specifying the encoding

Tags: python, unicode

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print "私"
print u"私"
```

the result:

```
ç§
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u79c1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Or, in Idle for both u"私" and "私":

```
>>> print "私"
Unsupported characters in input
```

I've followed all the advice I could find which says that I have to put the "coding" line under the shebang. All my web-browsers display kanji fine, and I can type it fine. But this garble comes out when I try and use it in Python :( Any ideas?

Comment: which Python version have you installed? IDLE 2.6.5 >>> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- >>> print "私" 私

Comment: what's your OS? what's your console or shell encoding?

Comment: @Wooble, the characters will be converted from UTF-8 input to an internal representation of codepoints. It's the internal representation that's being displayed in the error.

Comment: I have Python 2.7.1 installed on Win Vista. I tried your example, but still no luck :(

Comment: Running Python 2.7.1 on WinVista :/

Comment: Yeah, the Windows Command Prompt is pretty much a dead loss for Unicode(*). You can spit out `私` onto a web page with Python, or encode it into a file, but console IO and Unicode don't mix well under Windows. The nearest you can get is using `chcp 65001` and outputting with UTF-8-encoding, but there are significant problems with that.

Comment: (\*: when using the standard ANSI C stdio library, like Python and most other cross-platform languages do. There *is* also a Win32-special `WriteConsoleW` function which can be used to get Unicode output into the terminal window, but there are some problems making that work smoothly with the stdio model and even then, most characters won't render right for the default font settings. In summary, Windows+Unicode+console is still a right old mess and doesn't work well for many languages, not just Python.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a terminal or IDE that supports UTF8, or at least an encoding that supports Japanese. PythonWin, from the [Pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) extension library, is an IDE that will work.

Comment: I think this has solved it! Now using python 3.2 too! ^_^ I owe you a beer if you ever come to Japan.

Answer (score 6):

You specified the encoding of the source file and supposedly saved the files using UTF-8.

Still your `stdout` is using `ascii` so it is normal to fail.

You have an encoding issue not a decoding issue, Python does read your Unicode characters just fine, probably will be able to save them inside a file if you choose right encoding.

Still, stdout is not always Unicode compatible, especially on Windows.

You could do something like this: `sys.stdout.write(strin.encode(utf-8))` and you will not get an error, but this does not mean that you will see the characters on the screen.

Comment: Probably not Windows, with the `#!` at the start of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't like it. I'm running Python 2.7.1 on WinVista

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print unicode("私","UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

[sorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584984/python-still-wont-allow-japanese-characters-despite-specifying-the-encoding/6585188#6585188) is correct. There's another question which covers the same ground: [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

Python is applying a default encoding when it writes the output, and this encoding is *not* UTF-8.

The error from IDLE is because IDLE interprets input according to the system locale. Windows does not provide a locale that accepts UTF-8 input, so the default does not accept arbitrary Unicode. You may change the default with the simple instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843999/unicodeencodeerror-with-csvwriter/5447011#5447011). You'll still get the incorrect output without reencoding it.